# Will jQuery fail with client side XSLT

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I am looking to offload some processing to the client via client side XSLT. If I do this will my current JavaScript and jQuery still work?

Comment: I've changed the tags to "xslt", because up today there is no support of XSLT 2.0 on browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will, however if you load new elements via AJAX, you will need to use jQuery's **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method to ensure to elements are assigned events etc.